# Select From One Table where Does not exist in another

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have One table with People, and I have a second table to record if these people are "Absent"
The Absent Table (Absences) has the AbsenceID, PersonID and AbsentDate
The People Table has PersonID, FirstName, LastName

I am trying to make an SQL that will Get all the values from the People table, except for those that are Absent that day. So if for example Joe is listed in the Absences table and the AbsentDate is 11/01/2014, I want his name excluded from the query generated. This is what I have so far, but it shows me nothing:

I've tried below, but it returns all the rows:

```
SELECT * FROM People 
where not exists(Select PersonID 
                 from Absences 
                 where Absences.AbsentDate = 11/01/2014)
```

I'm sure it's something very simple that I am missing. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Access

Comment: what is datatype of `AbsentDate` column ??

Comment: Datatype of AbsentDate is Date/Time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM People 
where PersonID NOT IN (Select PersonID 
                       from Absences 
                       where DateValue(Absences.AbsentDate) = '20140111')
                                                                  ^ YYYYMMDD
```

Comment: This still returns all the rows from the People table when I tested it

Comment: @SSS Are you trying to return the persons name who was absent on that particular date ??? or who wasnt absent ??

Comment: Nono, Im trying to get all the values from the People table, except if they are listed as absent in the Absences table for that date.

SO if Joe, for example is Absent 11/01/2014 (And this is in the Absences table), he should not be in the results returned

Comment: well in this case this query should work. just try executing the inner query on it own and see if you get back Joe's ID ???

Comment: Ahh, you're right. IT returned nothing. I had to put the date as #1/11/2014# then it worked 

SELECT *
FROM People
WHERE PersonID Not In (Select Absences.PersonID from Absences where (Absences.AbsentDate) = #1/11/2014# )

Comment: well glad its sorted :)

Answer (score 2):

Since `AbsentDate` is a Date/Time field, it is storing both date and time and you are looking for equality on both. So '11/01/2014' is equivalent to searching for '11/01/2014 00:00:00.000', which I can almost bet nothing is stored as. So, the better method is to look for your value *between* '11/01/2014 00:00:00.0000' and '11/01/2014 23:59:59.999', which is what the `BETWEEN` operator does.

```
SELECT *
FROM People
LEFT JOIN Absences ON (People.PersonID = Absences.PersonID) AND (Absences.AbsentDate BETWEEN '11/01/2014' AND '12/01/2014')
WHERE AbsenceID IS NULL
```

I'm not a fan of `NOT IN` queries as they can be non-performant in general. But a `LEFT JOIN` where the joined table's primary key is `NULL` works quite nicely (assuming appropriate indexing, etc.)

Comment: I favour this approach over `NOT IN` as per the comments relating to performance. There is also the `NOT EXISTS` method which also is better than `NOT IN`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly You should mention which database are you using, with current information here is suggested answer
You should write query as follow

```
SELECT * FROM People where PersonID NOT in (Select PersonID 
                   from Absences 
                   where Absences.AbsentDate = sysdate)
```